# How can I set up and test the embedded ActiveMQ Artemis server in WildFly?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I have a standalone WildFly server running and would like to setup the embedded instance of ActiveMQ Artemis, but I'm not sure if I've done it correctly. Here are the related parts from my `standalone-full.xml`:

```xml
<server>
    ...
    <profile>
        ...
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.1">
            <server name="default">
                ...
                <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="activemq" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
                <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="activemq" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </http-connector>

                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="activemq"/>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="activemq">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </http-acceptor>
                ...
            </server>
        </subsystem>
        ...
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:12.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="other" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.undertow.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
            <server name="default-server">
                ...
                <http-listener name="activemq" socket-binding="activemq" enable-http2="true"/>
                ...
            </server>
        </subsystem>
        ...
    </profile>
    ...
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        ...
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>

        <socket-binding name="managemnet" interface="activemq-interface" port="${jboss.activemq.port:8081}"/>
        ...
    </socket-binding-group>
</server>
```

When I try to connect to the server at `tcp://localhost:8081` nothing seems to happen. Is there some tool out there that can help me examine the issue or do you guys know what might be wrong?

EDIT: Sorry guys I forgot to add a few things. I have standalone-full.xml That was a typo. However i was receving an error when using the standard configuration

> AMQ122005: Invalid "host" value "0.0.0.0" detected for "http-connector" connector.

So I assumed something was badly configured and that this was the cause for not being able to reach the imbedded artemis instance. I'm unsure what the standard port is for Artemis? is it localhost:9990?

Regarding versions

| Applicaiton | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Artemis | 2.19.1 |
| Wildfly | 26.1 |

I'm trying to connect wit the Quarkus JMS example described here
https://quarkus.io/guides/jms

Comment: @JustinBertram I've gone back to using the standalone-full.xml please see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AMQ122005` message is warning you that you've bound the "activemq" `socket-binding` which is being used by the "http-connector" `http-connector` to `0.0.0.0` which is not valid. A remote client looking up any JMS ConnectionFactory which is configured to use that connector will receive a stub pointing to `0.0.0.0` which won't work.

The only thing you *need* to do here is to instead bind the server to a concrete, remotely-accessible interface rather than `0.0.0.0`. Therefore, you don't need the extra `http-listener`, etc.

If you are using JNDI then you can connect embedded broker using a URL like this as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/main/helloworld-jms/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/jms/HelloWorldJMSClient.java):

```
http-remoting://host:8080
```

If you *aren't* using JNDI then you can connect to the embedded broker using a URL like:

```
tcp://host:8080?httpUpgradeEnabled=true
```

This is what you'd configure in Quarkus' `application.properties` in which case you can just ignore the `AMQ122005` message since you're not using JNDI.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. One more thing i'm curious about is, I can't seem to find any information about the default user. Do you just logg in without username/password?

Comment: I see you've asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74731136/how-can-i-add-a-user-that-can-connect-to-activemq-artemis-in-wildfly-via-quarkus) about this. I'll attempt to help there.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `standalone-full.xml` which has a complete working embedded Artemis broker.
Another solution with WildFly 27 is to use [Galleon](https://docs.wildfly.org/27/Galleon_Guide.html#installing-wildfly-using-galleon) and provision the **embedded-activemq** layer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion i am using standalone-full.xml please see my edit