# How can I add a user that can connect to ActiveMQ Artemis in WildFly via Quarkus JMS?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, quarkus, activemq-artemis

I have a WildFly application with an embedded ActiveMQ Artemis and I can't seem to figure how to debug it. It seems to connect fine since I'm getting no errors in the log, but I'm unable to read any queues. There is no error but nothing is happening.

I'm running the Quarkus JMS client 1.03 which is using org.apache.activemq » artemis-jms-client 2.19. The server is running WildFly 26.1 with the embedded ActiveMQ Artemis server 2.19.1 so the client and server should be compatible. However, I'm not sure if I've configured it correctly. I'm using the `standalone-full.xml`.

For testing I've added a user `test1`:

```bash
bash-4.4$ ./add-user.sh

What type of user do you wish to add?
 a) Management User (mgmt-users.properties)
 b) Application User (application-users.properties)
(a): b

Enter the details of the new user to add.
Using realm 'ApplicationRealm' as discovered from the existing property files.
Username : test1
Password recommendations are listed below. To modify these restrictions edit the add-user.properties configuration file.
 - The password should be different from the username
 - The password should not be one of the following restricted values {root, admin, administrator}
 - The password should contain at least 8 characters, 1 alphabetic character(s), 1 digit(s), 1 non-alphanumeric symbol(s)
Password :
WFLYDM0098: The password should be different from the username
Are you sure you want to use the password entered yes/no? yes
Re-enter Password :
What groups do you want this user to belong to? (Please enter a comma separated list, or leave blank for none)[  ]: guest
About to add user 'test1' for realm 'ApplicationRealm'
Is this correct yes/no? yes
Is this new user going to be used for one AS process to connect to another AS process?
e.g. for a slave host controller connecting to the master or for a Remoting connection for server to server Jakarta Enterprise Beans calls.
yes/no? yes
To represent the user add the following to the server-identities definition <secret value="dGVzdDE=" />
```

This is the log for creating that user. In my `standalone-full.xml` I have the role guest for ActiveMQ Artemis and the queue `prices` set up:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.1">
    <server name="default">
        ...
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        ...
        <address-setting name="jms.queue.prices" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" redelivery-delay="1000" max-delivery-attempts="0"/>
        ...
        <jms-queue name="prices" entries="java:/jms/queue/prices" durable="true"/>
        ...
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

My Quarkus client tries to connect with the following:

```
quarkus.artemis.url=tcp://localhost:8080
quarkus.artemis.username=test1
quarkus.artemis.password=test1
```

It has a consumer:

```java
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext(JMSContext.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)) {
            JMSConsumer consumer = context.createConsumer(context.createQueue("prices"));
            while (true) {
                Message message = consumer.receive();
                if (message == null) {
                    // receive returns `null` if the JMSConsumer is closed
                    return;
                }
                lastPrice = message.getBody(String.class);
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

and a producer:

```java
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext(JMSContext.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)) {
            context.createProducer().send(context.createQueue("prices"), Integer.toString(random.nextInt(100)));
        }
    }
```

It seem to connect just fine. I can see in the Quarkus log:

```
2022-12-08 14:29:59,596 DEBUG [org.apa.act.art.cor.cli.imp.ClientSessionFactoryImpl] (pool-10-thread-1) Trying reconnection attempt 0/1
2022-12-08 14:29:59,596 DEBUG [org.apa.act.art.cor.cli.imp.ClientSessionFactoryImpl] (pool-10-thread-1) Trying to connect with connectorFactory=org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory@6096907d and currentConnectorConfig: TransportConfiguration(name=null, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=8080&host=localhost
2022-12-08 14:29:59,596 DEBUG [org.apa.act.art.cor.rem.imp.net.NettyConnector] (pool-10-thread-1) Connector NettyConnector [host=localhost, port=8080, httpEnabled=false, httpUpgradeEnabled=false, useServlet=false, servletPath=/messaging/ActiveMQServlet, sslEnabled=false, useNio=true] using native epoll
2022-12-08 14:29:59,596 DEBUG [org.apa.act.art.cor.client] (pool-10-thread-1) AMQ211002: Started EPOLL Netty Connector version 4.1.82.Final to localhost:8080
2022-12-08 14:29:59,597 DEBUG [org.apa.act.art.cor.rem.imp.net.NettyConnector] (pool-10-thread-1) Remote destination: localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
2022-12-08 14:29:59,598 DEBUG [org.apa.act.art.cor.rem.imp.net.NettyConnector] (Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads)) Added ActiveMQClientChannelHandler to Channel with id = 6339db8b 
2022-12-08 14:29:59,598 DEBUG [org.apa.act.art.cor.cli.imp.ClientSessionFactoryImpl] (pool-10-thread-1) Connected with the currentConnectorConfig=TransportConfiguration(name=null, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=8080&host=localhost
2022-12-08 14:29:59,599 DEBUG [org.apa.act.art.cor.cli.imp.ClientSessionFactoryImpl] (pool-10-thread-1) Reconnection successful
```

So it seems to be working fine, but I can't seem to send or consume from the queue.

## Answers to Justin questions in the comments

### Have you tried adding `?httpUpgradeEnabled=true`

yes no change

`quarkus.artemis.url=tcp://localhost:8080?httpUpgradeEnabled=true`

### Can you check the consumer-count

Actually there does not even seem to be a session active. I tried to close the connection for my test user but it shown me a dialog "no connection for that user" So maybe it's not even connecting as I thought

### Why do you suspect the problem is with the user

I thought it might have something to do with some permission error. I was not sure if I was suppost to add the user to the "guest" group or not

But since I have in my config

```xml
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
```

EDIT2. Actually I see now in the log that quarkus seems to be missing permission for creating a consumer. So i guess "guest" role is not the correct one.

I assume that was corrected

Comment: Can you check the consumer-count of the `prices` queue once you create your consumer? Also, can you check the message-count after you send the message?

Comment: Have you tried adding `?httpUpgradeEnabled=true` to the URL configured in Quarkus' `application.properties`?

Comment: Why do you suspect the problem is with the user and not something else?

Comment: @JustinBertram Hi, i've updated my question with answers to your questions.